# Spring kafka error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaAwareTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

This is wired just started spring boot project with simple main class, it works fine without spring-kafka dependency but after adding `spring-kafka` and `spring-kafka-test` blows up with exception, github [here](https://github.com/Deadpool1111/SpringKafkaTest)

**gradle.build**

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

repositories {
    jcenter()
 }

dependencies {

     compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.0.RELEASE'
     compile group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka', version: '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka-test', version: '2.0.5.RELEASE'

 }
```

**Main class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkaMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(KafkaMain.class, args);
     }

  }
```

**Error**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-12-16 19:32:29.347 ERROR 39854 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Erro creating beanwithname'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaAwareTransactionManager not present
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at com.kafka.KafkaMain.main(KafkaMain.java:10) [bin/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaAwareTransactionManager not present
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Spring for Apache Kafka `2.0.x` is not compatible with Spring Boot `2.1.x`. You have to use `Spring-Kafka 2.2.x`. More over would be better to just rely on the dependency from Spring Boot per se. please, see https://start.spring.io/ for more info how properly start the project for Spring Boot.

And please, don’t duplicate your question in different places if that was not asked.

Comment: Huh? How is that possible? Actually, in reality , Spring Boot dictates all the versions of dependencies. And all the Spring Boot projects start from the mentioned generation tool. I would suggest to forget Spring Kafka version, of you use Spring Boot. Otherwise your use-case is not clear

Comment: Because you have upgraded Spring Boot, but not Spring Kafka. You need to learn how Spring Boot manages dependencies, so you need only upgrade its version and don’t worry about other versions

Comment: WORKS! - I moved to 2.2.4.RELEASE 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
And it is working!
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked for me @Artem, after degrading my spring version it worked as expected.

Comment: I have updated from 2.1.3 to 2.2.4, its working. Thanks a lot.